# Fullscreen JavaFX program in the same desktop with other applications?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I'm making a fullscreen JavaFX program, but I want it to run as a screensaver in the background with other applications simultaneously running on top of it. Right now, it automatically creates a separate desktop just for the program. Any solutions?

Comment: JavaFx creates GUI applications. Use plain java and create a class with no interface ...

Comment: So in that case, should I use Swing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing is definitely an option. Here is a place to start:

```
public class MyClass {

    public void myAction () {    

      // your logic goes here
      System.out.println("hello");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.myAction();

    }

}
```